# How do I save some API data from a v-for loop to my mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, vue.js

I am looping through some API data in Vue. I want to get the value that is displayed in my braces `{{ currency.description }}` and post that to my db.

I have tried for example `PostService.insertPost(e.target.innerHTML);`

Also have tried `this.$refs.criteria[0].innerHTML`

When console logged it shows exactly what I need, but when posted to the db it shows null.

**VUE template**

```
<ul  v-bind:key="currency.id" ref="criteria" v-for="currency in info">
  <li id="criteria" v-on:click="apiTest" >{{ currency.description }}</li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
apiTest(e) {   
  console.log(e.target.innerHTML);
  await PostService.insertPost(e.target.innerHTML);
}

data() {
  return{
    info: [],
```

My goal is to get the string value of `currency.description` into my db, instead of it showing up as `null`. I am guessing it has to do with my info array in my returned data, I am not sure how to go about it though.

Answer (score 2):

You want to make the loop on the **li**-element instead, and pass the description to the click function you're calling, like so:

```
// Template
<template>
  <ul>
    <li
      v-for="currency in info"
      v-bind:key="currency.id"
      v-on:click="apiTest(currency.description)">
      {{ currency.description }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>

// Method / Click function
async apiTest(description) {
  await PostService.insertPost(description);
}
```

Comment: This showed null:  description
:
null
createdAt
:
2019-06-04T08:26:24.199+00:00

Comment: Try console logging `description` in the `apiTest` function and see if it's null, else it might be a problem with your API.

Comment: I logged it, the description shows up perfect in the console.

Comment: It appears to be a problem with your API then.

Comment: Your method worked. I was missing my bodyParser.json middleware.

Answer (score 1):

Try using  await PostService.insertPost(currency.description); in $nextTick function. I think the problem may be the delay in loading the DOM since it is looping the list items.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="currency in info" :id="currency.id" @click="apiTest(currency)">{{ currency.description }} </li>
</ul>

apiTest: function (currency){
    //You can get the html element
    //var element = document,getElementById(currency.id)
    console.log(currency.description);
    await PostService.insertPost(currency.description);
```

}